# I have a keg, now what?

Tags: keg, kegerator

A co-worker of mine had a roommate move out and leave his brewing stuff behind, including two 5 gallon kegs (pictured below). Co-worker ended up giving them to me for free.

Obviously you need a CO2 tank, and connectors, but what size CO2 tank and are the 'Ball Lock Connectors' the right one in general/these specific ones? Can I use the same cleaning/rinsing chemicals on these (PBW/StarSan)?

Since I am a complete noob to the world of using my own keg, what else do I need?

[image: 5 Gallon Kegs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are ball lock kegs.  You can use PBW (or Oxiclean) to clean them and StarSan to sanitize.  Common CO2 tank sizes are 5 gal. and 20 gal.  5 gal. are more portable if that matters to you.  I use a 20 gal. and only need to get it filled once a year.  Here is some excellent info on cleaning, maintaining, and using kegs....

http://web.archive.org/web/20061113163320/http://www.bodensatz.com/staticpages/index.php?page=Soda-Kegs

Comment: CO2 tanks are measured in lbs, not gallons. As you allude, the size of the tank does not matter other than how big it is / how long it will last between refills.

Comment: I have a 10# tank, it cost me about $20 more originally, but refills at my home brew store are $19 compared to $15 for a 5# tank.

Comment: A 5# tank is fine for serving at least 10 kegs, including purging of the kegs at least 3 times while racking beer into them.  I also have had a slow leak completely deplete my recently filled tank.  So I find that 5# tanks are a balance between occasional refills and the risk of losing all that gas due to a leak in the system.  Another benefit is the 5# tank with regulator fits neatly in the kegerator where a 10# would not always...  Lastly, I've taken it on a few outings since its easy to transport being a little 5# tank.  So in conclusion I find 5# to be practical.

Answer (score 2):

This is the a great kegging reference too!

https://www.homebrewersassociation.org/attachments/0000/1312/Summerzym95-Kegging_How-To.pdf

Good pictures and informative reading with no fluff

Comment: +1 on this article from Zymurgy. It's great and I refer to it often. The illustrations by Randy Mosher are nice too.

Comment: Link is no longer valid...

Comment: The link worked for me just now. As an aside, Cornelius style kegs have a lot (a lot!) of seals and O-rings that can leak if they're not in perfect shape. Keg lube--food grade silicone grease--is a cheap way to make sure they stay that way. Most homebrew suppliers carry the stuff.

Answer (score 2):

BYO did a kegging guide that may be helpful. http://byo.com/store/byo-special-issues/guide-to-kegging